# Spread operator type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, transpiler

Running into the typescript error for the following

'error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.'

```
// Car.js
export default function (...deps) {
    return {
        wheel: new Wheel(...deps)
   };
}

// Wheel.js
export class Wheel {
       constructor(color, size, year) {
// . . .
```

I am trying to build es6 output but getting an error as to what type deps should get. Something like ...deps: any[] would be totally fine. Been trying a few things the last few days but haven't had any luck.

Does anyone more familiar with typescript know what type deps can take?

Comment: That's both rest (`function(...deps)`) *and* spread (`new Wheel(...deps)`). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'd be happy to hammer :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Between you, me, and the OP's comments on my deleted CW answer, yeah, I'm pretty sure.